How can I identify with letters differences between groups using emmeans
I have performed an anova and plot the differences between groups (YOB_tn) with emmeans. But I need to identify which levels arrange togheter (the letters netween contrasts) because it is impossible to extract that information from the plot.
What I did:
lm_IEP1<-lm(IEP ~  YOB_tn, data = anova_IEP1) 
summary.aov(lm_IEP1)
em<-emmeans(lm_IEP1, "YOB_tn") 
plot(em)`

enter image description here
How can any of you help me to solve this?
Thanks :)
